# Authentication failure with passport middleware never gets invoked

Tags: node.js, passport.js, middleware, passport-local

The following program uses [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password) for username/password authentication. I do not what mistake am I making, but I am always redirected to the failure page, i.e back again to the login page.

```
    var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , express = require('express');


var app = express();

app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
     console.log(username + ':username');
     console.log(password + ':password');
     return done(null, [{username:'foo'}]);
  }
));

app.get('/login',(req,resp) => {
    var options = {
        root: __dirname + '/public/'
    };

    resp.sendFile('login.html',options);
});

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/login'})
);
```

I am trying to understand the working of `passportjs` and I see that the middleware `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(` never gets invoked. I do not know the reason but may be it could be the root cause of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe passport need session try add `app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));` before passport config.

You must name your strategy and serialize user

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
     console.log(username + ':username');
     console.log(password + ':password');
     return done(null, [{username:'foo'}]);
  }
));
```

You call this strategy by name in this eg `local`

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/login'})
);
```

Comment: Still not entering the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

So I was missing `body parser` module required by passportjs to parse the post request. Here is the complete code:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , express = require('express')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app = express();

app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
     console.log(username + ':username');
     console.log(password + ':password');
     return done(null, {username:username});
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   done(null, user);
});


app.get('/login',(req,resp) => {
    var options = {
        root: __dirname + '/public/'
    };

    resp.sendFile('login.html',options);
});

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/login'})
);
```